# How to modify innerHTML in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, innerhtml

How to modify innerHTML in selenium python, i tried the code, but it didnt worked, can anyone, please help me out.

```
xpath_desc = '//*[@id="cke_1_contents"]/div/p'
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_desc)
HTML = 'Hello World This is <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>'
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('innerHTML', {HTML}", element)
```

Comment: Please clarify that "it didnt worked"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried changing the `innerHTML` of a `<p>` tag and I am able to do it using the below code.

The HTML code which I have used to recreate the scenario -

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>ForTesting</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="myP">Change the Paragraph Here</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Code -

```
# Change the InnerHTML of a P Tag.

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
action = ActionChains(driver)

driver.get("URL")
time.sleep(5)

Para_Element = driver.find_element_by_id("myP")
print(Para_Element.text)
# driver.execute_script("var ele=arguments[0]; ele.innerHTML = 'Successfully Changed the Content';", Para_Element)

driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('myP').appendChild(document.createElement('a'))")
element = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("a")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('href', 'https://www.google.com/')", element)
driver.execute_script("var ele=arguments[0]; ele.innerHTML = 'Google';", element)

Para_Element = driver.find_element_by_id("myP")
print(Para_Element.text)
```

Let me know if you have any questions about that. Please take the reference from the above code and then try.

Comment: Hi Swaroop, This one works fine, but what if i want to enter html content in it, can you help me on it.i want to put it a variable and call it on

Para_Element = driver.find_element_by_id("myP")
HTML = 'Hello World This is <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>'
driver.execute_script("var ele=arguments[0]; ele.innerHTML = '{HTML}';", Para_Element)

Comment: Sure i will give it a try and post the updated code.

Comment: @sunny9495 I have edited my code, please give it a try and let me know the outcome.

Comment: Hi Swaroop, 

Thanks alot for the help, but iam inserting not only the given html code mate,iam using different html code to perform actions on it, iam expecting like this bro.

content = 'Hello World This is <a href='http://google.com'>Google</a>, This is <a href="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
driver.execute_script("var ele=arguments[0]; ele.innerHTML = '{content}';", Para_Element)

I want to insert what ever the html code given on content variable on page mate.